# Do files in the "Header Search Paths" get compiled?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

or is it just used to reference other files so it doesn't crash at startup? I guess Im just a little confused as to what it's doing.

(I have almost no ios experience, I do my development using React Native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from Quick Help in Xcode:

> HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS
>
> Description
>
> This is a list of paths to folders to be searched by the **compiler** for included or imported header files when **compiling** C, Objective-C, C++, or Objective-C++. Paths are delimited by whitespace, so any paths with spaces in them need to be properly quoted.

Files in the “Header Search Paths” get compiled when they are included or imported in other files which get compiled. “Header Search Paths” is not used at runtime.